# uivisualeffect view ios swift navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

Hi iam getting a blue color visualeffectview on my navigation bar on running. i didnt changed any background colour .how to fix this issue please help. [image]

code to navigate to my viewcontroller from  a mainviewcontroller

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: CommonStoryBoard.List, bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: CommonNavigationControllers.ListViewController )
self.show(vc as UIViewController, sender: vc)
```

Comment: You chage navigation bar background color?

Comment: @jay navigation bar color is gery colour you can see in that picture. visual effect view override bar. dont know how its coming like that.